# How to configure IntelliJ's Java Code Style so to wrap right hand of the assigment when long taking priority over chained method call

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting

I've been having an issue to configure IntelliJ's Java code style to my liking. When I type some operation with streams I have something like this:

```
    VeryVeryVeryLongNamedClazz instance = container.getList()
                                                   .stream()
                                                   .filter(element -> element.getRole()
                                                                             .equals("CFG"))
                                                   .findFirst()
                                                   .get();
```

When class names and variable names are quite long, and if the code is quite nested, the whole code block gets shifted far too right to the right for my liking.

Something like this would be much more to my liking:

```
    VeryVeryVeryLongNamedClazz instance = 
            container.getList()
                     .stream()
                     .filter(element -> element.getRole()
                                               .equals("CFG"))
                     .findFirst()
                     .get();
```

Is there a way to configure the Java code style so that right hand of the assignment gets wrapped to the next line when the line is too long, or that the assignment rule takes priority over method call rule?

EDIT:
To be more clear, what I'm looking for is that on wrapping, the assignment rule is done *before* chained method rule.

Comment: Not to mention that I would prefer that chained method calls are wrapped always only for streams, and that other methods are allowed to exist in the same line until end of line is reached...

Comment: Did you already try to go: **Settings -> Editor -> Code Style** and have a look?

Comment: @AlbertoUrsino everything I tried did not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to configure the Java code style so that right hand of
>   the assignment gets wrapped to the next line when the line is too long

With 'Hard Wrap' at 60 and your code sample, I was able to achieve the desired result on hitting `Ctrl+Alt+L` using the following settings under **File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java > Wrapping and Braces**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

> I would prefer that chained method calls are wrapped always only for streams, and that other methods are allowed to exist in the same line until end of line is reached

Don't think it's possible with current settings. But you can always submit a [new feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue) to the IntelliJ IDEA developers on YouTrack.

Comment: Before I try out your suggestion, I found the feature request I was looking for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122600

Personally, seems the fix is not too complicated, but I don't have the time to set up development of IntelliJ. 

On the other hand, I do have the time to tweak the code style, so there's that :D

Comment: I am sorry to report, but your suggestion is not working for me. If I put the entire assignment in a single line end then press `Cmd-Alt-L` I get the result as in the first code example :( I will update my question.